# JAX-RS run a function only once

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am new to JAX-RS, and I created a simple webservice. That is as follows

```
public class WebService {
    public WebService(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/testGet")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response get() throws IOException{
         return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine. Only thing I want to know is I want to execute a function only once in my entire webservice lifecycle. So that I can read properties file. Otherwise I'll endup reading it every request.

Any Suggesitions ?

Comment: Take a look at http://dropwizard.io. It builds on top of Jersey and provides nicer APIs for this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't think it's related to JAX-RS. It's a common configuration requirement.

Comment: I would suggest to do the operations such as *Propertied file reading etc.* while your servlet container is initialized first time as suggested by @ChristianStrempfer and use the prepared object throughout your application life cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried a static constructor?

```
public class OneTimer {
    static {
        System.out.println("executed only once");
    }
}
```

or, if you turn your REST class into a singleton-ejb you could do something like this

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class SingletonEJB {

    @PostConstruct
    public void oneTimeOnly() {
        System.out.println("one time after every construct");
    }
}
```

I prefer the static constructor approach

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static boolean that changes after the first time you called the function. (And check on this boolean before executing the function.)